# Split fixed width file by each (variable length) multi line record

Tags: ssis

I have a fixed width file from which I need to separate only certain records.
This wouldn't be too much of an issue if each record had the same number of lines, unfortunately this isn't the case.

Each records begins with BKT and ends with 2 lines beginning with BKP.

Here's an example.

```
BKT0000000406000001  012057           
BKS00000005242105200000010571866887336 5FFFV   20261942
BKS00000006302105200000010571866887336
BKS00000007392105200000010571866887336
BKS00000008462105200000010571866887336
BAR00000009642105200000010571866887336
BAR00000010652105200000010571866887336
BAR00000011662105200000010571866887336
BMD00000012752105200000010571866887336
BMD00000013762105200000010571866887336
BKP0000001484210520000001EX        000
BKP0000001584210520000001CA        000
BKT0000002806000003  017057           
BKS00000029242105170000030573833622915 1FVVV   20229672
BKS00000030302105170000030573833622915
BKS00000031302105170000030573833622915
BKS00000032392105170000030573833622915
BKI00000033622105170000030573833622915
BKI00000034622105170000030573833622915
BKI00000035632105170000030573833622915
BKI00000036632105170000030573833622915
BAR00000037642105170000030573833622915
BAR00000038652105170000030573833622915
BAR00000039662105170000030573833622915
BKF00000040812105170000030573833622915
BCC0000004182210517000003CCAX3499  002
BCX0000004283210517000003CCAX3499  010
BKP0000004384210517000003CCAX3499  000
BKP0000004484210517000003CA        000
```

How can I separate each record and create 2 new files, one with every record containing 20261942 on the second line and one with everything else?

I have done a little work with SSIS in the past but have been furloughed since last April and have forgotten all but the most basic stuff.

Comment: You probably want more than you are asking for. Why do you want to create two files? Why would you not just want to process the file in one pass? Anyway, you will need to use a script component for this.

Comment: I need the two files because we will be processing one file now and might need to process the other data later.
I was hoping to be able to do this without a script component but if that's the way to go...